# Directing an application to find a DLL in a specific location

Tags: windows, visual-c++

I'm working with a native C++/Win32/MFC application built using Visual Studio 2010 Pro on Windows 7 x64.  The application is linked with some other DLLs using their .lib files.

I'd like to be able to run this application and have it find the DLLs in their respective directories without 1) having to put the DLLs in the application directory or 2) add the DLL directories to the PATH or 3) resort to dynamically loading the DLLs and having to lookup stuff at runtime.

Is this even possible?  Is there some way to direct the OS loader to go find the DLLs in an arbitrary location I specify without having to add that to the PATH?

Comment: If the DLLs are not loaded dynamically and not delay loaded (not sure about that one), I don't think you can do anything. The load will happen before your code gets called. If using `LoadLibrary`, you *can* try [SetDllDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms686203%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to keep any code changes to a minimum. Last resort would be a .bat or .cmd file to launch that sets the PATH beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

**Basics:**

- In Visual Studio project settings, keep everything default specially in **Release** configuration.
- Ensure that you give **Release** build to the client (Where VS wouldn't have been installed).
- If client OS is 32-bit, you must give 32-bit. Otherwise you can give 64-bit (Release build in any case).

Now comes **distribution** and **VC++ runtime** library. 
You must install appropriate Visual C++ Runtime on client's machine,
   ensuring that:

- The version should match (VC7, VC8,.. VC14 etc.)
- The bit-ness should match. If your application is 32-bit, you need 32-bit
  redistributable, and same for x64.
- The service pack version must also
  match!

It should be noted that all of them can co-exist! VC10 RTM, VC10 SP2, VC10 x64 RTM.. all can co-exist

Comment: It sounds like you're assuming the DLLs in question are the runtime  library DLLs.  That is not the case, these are other DLLs also built from source which are used by the application but which are built in different directory locations.

Comment: Then you need to build those DLLs as static library, which will club entire object code into EXE.